I need help finding a Lego Star Wars set
I need help finding a Lego set I got for Christmas about 4-5 years ago. It was a gray spaceship with three engines. It wasn't small but not huge either. It wasn't a spaceship with multiple wings just two. The only other thing I remember is that the color inside of the engines was blue. It would be great if you knew one that looked like this or was similar to the above.

Hi tgamr and welcome to Bricks.SE! Are you looking for the set based on just the description because you don't have it at hand now to take a photo of it? If this is the case, then any information could be useful, like if there were any minifigures (how many, who, what colour, etc), what distinct parts were visible, what base and accent colours did it have, how big was the box, what did the instruction sheet look like, etc. Can you recall anything else?

thats the problem i was a child back the so i cant really remember anything but i know that it wasnt long but rataher like a triangle

I'd recommend browsing here, after setting the sorting to "Year released (desc)". There you'll definitely find the set you're looking for, but if I had to guess, you probably had 75315 Imperial Light Cruiser.

This checks the following boxes:

Was sold between 2021 and 2022
Is dominantly gray
Has three engines
Not small but not huge either
Has two "wings"
Has blue glow inside the engines

Although it is rather long, but still a bit triangular.
Let us know if you have found the one you're looking for, by writing an answer here and accepting it.
Edit
I've also found these, but they don't match all the listed criteria above - maybe you misremembered something?

75347 TIE Bomber
75348 Mandalorian Fang Fighter vs TIE Interceptor
75357 Ghost & Phantom II
75360 Yoda's Jedi Starfighter
75362 Ahsoka Tano's T-6 Jedi Shuttle
75363 The Mandalorian N-1 Starfighter Microfighter
75323 The Justifier
75325 The Mandalorian's N-1 Starfighter
75314 The Bad Batch Attack Shuttle
75186 The Arrowhead
75190 First Order Star Destroyer
75147 StarScavenger

After the comment saying you're not sure if it was Star Wars, you could still browse the Brickset database for the relevant years. You said 4-5 years ago, so maybe start with the sets released 3 years ago (in case there was a mistake in the estimation) and go until the ones from 7-9 years ago (sets can remain in stores after they are officially discontinued). If you are sure it was a LEGO set, you'll find it there, as Brickset lists all sets ever released. However, there are no such databases for 3rd party sets, so if it turns out yours was not genuine LEGO, the search will get a lot more difficult.
Anyways, try to remember more details: how big it was, maybe estimate the size based on other objects (your hand, a vase, other toys, etc.); did it come in a sealed box, if yes, how big was the box; perhaps ask other people who might have seen it what they recall; check if any photos were taken on that day; and so on. Keep in mind that while we are trying to help you, it is ultimately you who needs to put in the work to find what you're looking for.

thanks but it aint it

@tgamr Did you also check the first link?

yeah now i not even sure it from starwars

@tgamr Have you managed to find it?
